# Creating Histogram with Additional Data Element

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, histogram

I have a dataframe with quantities and values of different categories summarized. I need to visualize this to show how many categories are under different groups of quantities and what is the value they have earlier in summation.

Sample dataframe to use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat': ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'],
                   'count': [5,10,50,20,3,18,28,93,42,31],
                   'value': [100,245,890,510,85,690,730,2470,1870,1180],
                  })
```

I created the histogram for counts using this:

```
df.plot(kind='hist',y='count',bins=[0,20,40,60,80,100])
```

This will show me the distribution of 'cat' in different groups (classes) of 'count' variable.

Now, for each such class, I need to have a total of 'value' visualized on the same chart. Either just the sum shown as a number against each histogram bar or a line with secondary y-axis on the right of the same chart (axes).

This will enable me to show that ***categories having count of (say) 0-20 have earned value in total of 1220***. [value(A+B+E+F)]

Also, you may suggest if instead of histogram, I should be using some other chart to visualize this statement better.

Comment: I could plot specific values on the axes using coordinates on the axes and giving specific values to those coordinates. But that requires manual effort when the data changes or the histogram bins are increased or decreased. Any way to do this through a simple command or mixing two different charts?

Comment: I found that something called plotting an Empirical Cummulative Distribution Function might be a better option here. Though I don't know what this is. I will update once I get to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the pandas.cut() method to create bins manually and generated another dataframe which was aggregate of the earlier one.

This is the closest that I could come up with. But I still do not get a clear visualization of what I want to show.

```
df['Bins'] = pd.cut(df['count'],bins=range(0,70,10))
df1 = df.groupby('Bins').agg({'Bins':'count','value':'sum'})
df1.plot(kind='bar',subplots=True,figsize=(15,8))
plt.show()
```